# Ambiguity with location tag; geolocation or JavaScript property?

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms, retag-request

The [location](/questions/tagged/location) tag has quite a few answers but I feel doesn't convey the right information and would be hard to write a wiki for that didn't copy [geolocation](/questions/tagged/geolocation).  The vast majority of these could probably be retagged to [geolocation](/questions/tagged/geolocation) in fact.

However some of the questions for this tag are referring to [`document.location`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.location) in JavaScript.  What would be a suitable tag for questions concerning this use of the keyword 'location'?  Would it be better to simply remove the tag from these questions altogether?  Colloquially I think location translates better to geolocation as compared to a JavaScript property.

Answer (score 1):

I would say to remove the [location](/questions/tagged/location) tag from the question, for two reasons.

The first is that it's a horribly broad tag and doesn't really do a good job of categorizing the content (as your question shows).

The second being that we don't really encourage tags that are that granular for an API (i.e. member names), as it makes the tag do incredibly specific.

Tags are like Goldilocks, they can't be too broad or too specific, they have to be *just right*.

Comment: +1 for the Goldilocks reference.  I'm trying to squeeze a Calvin & Hobbes in somewhere.